# Get JSON Encode Data PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have json data stored in database with field name "field_form" like this:

```
[
    {
        "panjang": "200",
        "tipe_data": "text",
        "nama_field": "nama lengkap"
    },
    {
        "panjang": "201",
        "tipe_data": "number",
        "nama_field": "tahun lahir"
    }
]
```

I need to get "nama_field" data in PHP CodeIgniter controller, when i get the data with code:

```
$data_form = $this->perizinan_model->get_sub_field_form($id_jenis_izin)->result();

foreach($data_form as $data_field){
   var_dump(json_decode($data_field->field_form));
}
```

var_dump result is

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (3) { ["panjang"]=> string(3) "200" ["tipe_data"]=> string(4) "text" ["nama_field"]=> string(12) "nama lengkap" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (3) { ["panjang"]=> string(3) "201" ["tipe_data"]=> string(6) "number" ["nama_field"]=> string(11) "tahun lahir" } }
```

But, i just want to get nama_field data, and store it on array. Thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your data structure. It is object inside array then this is the code.

```php
$nama_fields = [];
foreach($data_form as $data_field){
    $jsonData = json_decode($data_field->field_form);

    if (is_array($jsonData)) {
        foreach ($jsonData as $index => $item) {
            if (isset($item->nama_field)) {
                $nama_fields[] = $item->nama_field;
            }
        }
    }
}

// then use $nama_fields variable.
var_dump($nama_fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `json_decode` the JSON object and convert it to an associative array.

```
foreach($data_form as $data_field){
   $data = json_decode($data_field->field_form, true);

  // the you can access your data as an array
  var_dump($data['nama_field']);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but its return undefined nama_field. When i try dump $data, its return: array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["panjang"]=> string(3) "200" ["tipe_data"]=> string(4) "text" ["nama_field"]=> string(12) "nama lengkap" } [1]=> array(3) { ["panjang"]=> string(3) "201" ["tipe_data"]=> string(6) "number" ["nama_field"]=> string(11) "tahun lahir" } }